# finding sums in 2 dimentional arrays java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

A project I am doing requires me to find horizontal and vertical sums in 2 dimensional arrays. So pretty much its a word search (not using diagonals) but instead of finding words, the program looks for adjacent numbers that add up to int sumToFind. The code below is what I have come up with so far to find horizontal sums, and we are supposed to implement a public static int[][] verticalSums as well. Since I have not yet completed the program I was wondering, first of all, if what I have will work and, secondly, how the array verticalSums will differ from the code below. Thank you

```
public static int[][] horizontalSums(int[][] a, int sumToFind) {

    int i;
    int start;
    int sum = 0;
    int copy;
    int [][] b = new int [a[0].length] [a.length];

    for (int row = 0; row < a.length; row++) {

        for ( start = 0; start < a.length; start++) {
            i = start;
            sum = i;

            do {
                i++;
                sum = sum + a[row][start]; 
            } 
            while (sum < sumToFind);

            if(sum == sumToFind) {

                for (copy = start; copy <= i; copy++) {
                    b[copy] = a[copy];
                }
            }

            for (i = 0; i < a[0].length; i++) {
                if (b[row][i] != a[row][i]) 
                b[row][i] = 0;      
            }

        }
    }

    return b;

}
```

Comment: To test if it is working, write some test code or run it through the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't work.... (and your question is "if what I have will work?" so this is your answer).

You declare the `int[][] b` array as `new int [a[0].length] [a.length]` but I think you mean: `new int [a.length] [a[0].length]` because you base the `row` variable off `a.length`, and later use `a[row][i]`.

So, if your array is 'rectangular' rather than square, you will have index-out-of-bounds problems on your `b` array.

Your comments are non-existent, and that makes your question/code hard to read.

Also, you have the following problems:

1. you set `sum = i` where `i = start` and `start` is the index in the array, not the array value. So, your sum will never be right because you are summing the index, not the array value.
2. in the do..while loop you increment `i++` but you keep using `sum = sum + a[row][start]` so you just keep adding the value to itself, not the 'next' value.

At this point it is obvious that your code is horribly broken.

You need to get friendly with someone who can show you how the debugger works, and you can step through your problems in a more contained way.

Answer (score 0):

Test is very simple

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] a = {{1, 2}, {1, 0}};

    int[][] result = Stos.horizontalSums(a, 1);

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));
}
```

Result

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
```

When you fix this problem, then this should print something like this

```
[[1, 2], [1, 0]]
```

Comment: Look at @rolfl answer